# Trello Integration

Tags: trello

I don't know if this is possible. I'm trying to integrate Trello with a google App and want to be able to let the user work with a Trello card in the app and not have to visibly go to the Trello site.

Can I import an actual card into the app or only the data?

Martin Rowe

Answer (score 4):

If your Google App provides a way to host a web page, you should be able to host the page for the card.  Just use the card's URL which is available through the API by using something similar to:

```
/1/cards/<cardId>?fields=url&key=<appKey>[&token=<userToken>]
```

Otherwise, I think that your only option is to receive the data through the API (by removing the `fields=url&` from above) and rebuild the UI of a card within your app.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I've decided to use a iframe. Thanks for your time.